# how to solve an matrix equation that is similar to a sylvester equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

during an algorithmn, I have to solve an equation of the form
$$AXD-XBD=C$$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,$X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$,$B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$,$D\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.

The unknown $X$ has to be solved but I don't know how, because I just know sylvester equations.
Can someone help?

Comment: Can we assume that matrices are invertible?

Comment: ^If $m$, $n$, and $p$ are distinct, then $B$ is the only square matrix in the problem. So, the other matrices are not invertible.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 That's only true in a sense. You can still find a matrix $D^{-1}$ so that $DD^{-1}=I$ even when $D$ is not square. In fact $D^{-1}=D^T(DD^T)^{-1}$. It's the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse.

Answer (score 2):

If the null space of $D$ is not contained in the null space of $C$, there is obviously no solution.

Now suppose the null space of $D$ is  contained in the null space of $C$.  Let $D^+$ be the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $D$.
Solve the Sylvester equation $AX - XB = C D^+$.  Then $AXD - XBD = C D^+ D = C $ (since  the range of $I - D^+ D$ is the null space 
of $D$).